# Do links in notes posted on Facebook pass value?

Tags: seo

The code for links posted within notes appear as so:

```
<a href="/note_redirect.php?note_id=396569262314&h=0b433086f1b39a09b03ca717f5517705&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.justiceclaus.com" target="_blank" title="http://www.justiceclaus.com">justiceclaus.com</a>
```

As where links everywhere else are explicitly no-follow like this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.justiceclause.com%2F&amp;h=f24fa" onmousedown="UntrustedLink.bootstrap($(this), &quot;f24fa&quot;, event);" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">http://www.justiceclause.com/</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in belief that every link provides some value even if it is very little. It's not like it's going to pass the juice link on the facebook homepage would but even no follow and redirect links mean something.

Answer (score 0):

Having some no follow back links helps with ranking. I think to Google it basically looks like if you have certain percentage of back links as no follow - you aren't a spammer. Besides that it doesn't give you any link juice, doesn't pass any values or keywords.

On the other hand, links from Facebook normally bring in traffic = potential customers. Therefor there might be a different kind of value you're looking at here.